# How to selected option in multiselect UI Component in Magento2

Tags: magento2.3, uicomponent, multiselect

I need to select one or more option before rendering this page. I tried several ways but unable to find an exact way to solve my issue.

I need to select Tea and Other Tea Option before loading.

[image]

**Form.php**

```
   protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('row_data');
    
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create(['data' => ['id' => 'edit_form', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post']]);
    
    if ($model) {
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Review Details'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']);
        $fieldset->addField('entity_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'entity_id']);
    } else {
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Review Details'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']);
    }
    $fieldset->addField(
        'shop_title',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'seller_name',
            'label' => __('Seller Name'),
            'title' => __('Seller Name'),
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'required' => true,
            'disabled' => $model ? true : false,
        ]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'categoryList',
        'multiselect',
        [
            'name' => 'categoryList[]',
            'label' => __('Categories'),
            'title' => __('Categories'),
            'values' => $model->getData('categoryList'),
            'disabled' => false

        ]
    );

    $form->setValues($model ? $model->getData() : '');
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

**$model->getData('categoryList') Array**

```
array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'label' => 'Wood & Wooden Products',
        'value' => '56',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'label' => 'Food, Feed & Beverages',
        'value' => '35',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'label' => 'Tea',
        'value' => '32',
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'label' => 'Other Tea',
        'value' => '167',
      ),
    )
```

**array generate as below**

```
  foreach ($categoryListArray as $catId)
  {
     $categoryObj = $this->categoryRepository->get($catId);
     $name = $categoryObj->getName();
     $options[] = ['label' => $name, 'value' => $catId ,];

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in jquery:

first load js in your page then try below code

```
require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/backend/form'
    ], function($){

        //simple way
        $("#categoryList").val(["32", "167"]);   

        //Iterate through the loop using the value in a dynamic selector that utilizes the attribute selector.

        var values="32,167";
        $.each(values.split(","), function(i,e){
        $("#categoryList option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
        });

    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I also found the solution for it bit different way in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I Found the Solution for this.

```
$premiumCategory = json_encode($model->getData('premium_category'));
//output of $premiumCategory = ["32","167"]; 

$fieldset->addField(
            'categoryList',
            'multiselect',
            [
                'name' => 'categoryList[]',
                'label' => __('Categories'),
                'title' => __('Categories'),
                'values' => $model->getData('categoryList'),
                'disabled' => false,
                'style'     => 'width: 100%',
                'after_element_html' => '<script>
                 require([
                    "jquery"
                ], function(jQuery){
                        var arr = ' . $premiumCategory . ';
                       jQuery.each( arr, function( i, val ) {
                           jQuery("#categoryList option[value=\'" + val + "\']").attr("selected","selected");
                        });
                   });
                    </script>',
            ]
        );
```