# Select items in multiselect on Product form in Admin area

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, adminform, multiselect-attribute, magento2.4.4

On the Product edit form in the Admin area, I have added a multiselect field by overwriting the `modifyMeta()` method on `Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier` as so:

```
<?php
namespace Dotancohen\Foobar\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Select;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\MultiSelect;

class Features extends AbstractModifier {

    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $meta_extend = [
            'dc-product-foobar' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'label' => __('Foobar'),
                            'collapsible' => true,
                            'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => 'data.dc-product-foobar',
                            'sortOrder' => 10,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'children' => [
                    'testmultiselect' => [
                        'arguments' => [
                            'data' => [
                                'config' => [
                                    'label'         => __('Multiselect Element'),
                                    'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                                    'formElement'   => MultiSelect::NAME,
                                    'dataScope'     => 'testmultiselect',
                                    'dataType'      => Text::NAME,
                                    'sortOrder'     => 10,
                                    'options'       => [
                                        ['value' => '0', 'label' => __('One')],
                                        ['value' => '1', 'label' => __('Two')],
                                        ['value' => '2', 'label' => __('Three')],
                                        ['value' => '3', 'label' => __('Four')],
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        $meta = array_replace_recursive($meta, $meta_extend);
        return $meta;
    }

}
```

This code does properly add the Multiselect field. **How can I now set specific values as being selected?** The data is coming from an outside process, not the database, so I need to set the values here in PHP.

I've tried the obvious adding of elements `'selected' => 'selected'` and `'selected' => true` to the relevant values' arrays, like so:

```
'options'       => [
    ['value' => '0', 'label' => __('One'), 'selected' => 'selected'],
    ['value' => '1', 'label' => __('Two'), 'selected' => true],
    ['value' => '2', 'label' => __('Three')],
    ['value' => '3', 'label' => __('Four')],
],
```

Neither approach worked. Then I tried to add some JavaScript that might select the elements, as [suggested here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/339458/how-to-selected-option-in-multiselect-ui-component-in-magento2):

```
// Javascript on the fieldset itself
'config' => [
    'after_element_html' => '<script>require([], function(){console.log("Hello, fieldset!");});</script>',
    'label' => __('Features'),
    'collapsible' => true,
    'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
    'dataScope' => 'data.dc-product-foobar',
    'sortOrder' => 10,
],

// Javascript on the Multiselect element
'config' => [
    'after_element_html' => '<script>require([], function(){console.log("Hello, Multiselect!");});</script>',
    'label'         => __('Multiselect Element'),
    'componentType' => Field::NAME,
    'formElement'   => MultiSelect::NAME,
    'dataScope'     => 'testmultiselect',
    'dataType'      => Text::NAME,
    'sortOrder'     => 10,
    'options'       => [
        ['value' => '0', 'label' => __('One')],
        ['value' => '1', 'label' => __('Two')],
        ['value' => '2', 'label' => __('Three')],
        ['value' => '3', 'label' => __('Four')],
    ],
],
```

However **the JavaScript is not being invoked**. I do see that that the two `after_element_html` values are appearing in some escaped JSON string in the HTML, but the `<script>` tag itself is not in the DOM.

**How can I either assert that specific options' values are to be selected in the PHP array, or how can I get that JavaScript invoked so that I could select them using JavaScript?**

**Edit:** Here is the complete code file:

```
<?php
namespace DotanCohen\Foobar\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\MultiSelect;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;

class Features extends AbstractModifier {

    const FIELDSET_NAME = 'so-test-fieldset';
    const FIELD_NAME = 'testmultiselect';

    protected $_locator;


    public function __construct(LocatorInterface $locator)
    {
        $this->_locator = $locator;
    }


    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        $product = $this->_locator->getProduct();
        $additionalData = [
            self::FIELD_NAME => ["0", "2"]
        ];

        $productId = $product->getId() ?? null;
        $data[$productId] = $data[$productId] ?? [];
        $data[$productId]['product'] = $data[$productId]['product'] ?? [];
        $data[$productId]['product'] = array_merge($data[$productId]['product'], $additionalData);

        return $data;
    }


    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $meta_extend = [
            self::FIELDSET_NAME => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'label' => __('Features'),
                            'collapsible' => true,
                            'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => 'data.'.self::FIELDSET_NAME,
                            'sortOrder' => 10,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'children' => [
                    self::FIELD_NAME => [
                        'arguments' => [
                            'data' => [
                                'config' => [
                                    'label'         => __('Multiselect from PHP'),
                                    'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                                    'formElement'   => MultiSelect::NAME,
                                    'dataScope'     => self::FIELD_NAME,
                                    'dataType'      => Text::NAME,
                                    'sortOrder'     => 30,
                                    'options'       => [
                                        ['value' => '0', 'label' => __('One')],
                                        ['value' => '1', 'label' => __('Two')],
                                        ['value' => '2', 'label' => __('Three')],
                                        ['value' => '3', 'label' => __('Four')],
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ];

        $meta = array_replace_recursive($meta, $meta_extend);
        return $meta;
    }


}
```

And here is the relevant `etc/adminhtml/di.xml` section:

```
    <!-- Override magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/CustomOptions.php to filter Customizable Options -->
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions">
        <plugin name="dotancohen_foobar_custom_options" type="DotanCohen\Foobar\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>

    <!-- CustomOptions.php: DI on constructor -->
    <type name="DotanCohen\Foobar\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="locator" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Comment: You don't need to specify `locator` argument in `di` for this case. You need to specify any arguments only if you want to specify specific class which is implement `LocatorInterface` which is different from defined in preference. Othercase is just overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure that you've provided not full code, because the provided code will not work

The abstract class `\Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier` implements `\Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\ModifierInterface` and you should implement 2 methods `modifyData` and `modifyMeta`.

The method `modifyMeta` updates metadata for product edit form

The method `modifyData` updates values for product data which will be used for render product form data.

In your metadata you are specified scope as `testmultiselect` and in `modifyData` method you should to be sure you are specified the correct values for your data.

How it should be (example)

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Features.php`

**[Updated]**

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\MultiSelect;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;

class Features extends AbstractModifier
{
    protected const FIELDSET_NAME = 'so-test-fieldset';
    protected const FIELD_NAME    = 'testmultiselect';

    protected LocatorInterface $locator;

    public function __construct(LocatorInterface $locator)
    {
        $this->locator = $locator;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data): array
    {
        $product = $this->locator->getProduct();

        $additionalData = [];
        if (!$product->getId()) {
        // some logic for default values if needed
        $additionalData[self::FIELD_NAME] = '0,2';
        } else {
            // some logic to retrieve product data
            $additionalData[self::FIELD_NAME] = $product->getData(self::FIELD_NAME);
        }

        $productId                   = $product->getId() ?? null;
        $data[$productId]            = $data[$productId] ?? [];
        $data[$productId]['product'] = $data[$productId]['product'] ?? [];
        $data[$productId]['product'] = array_merge($data[$productId]['product'], $additionalData);

        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta): array
    {
        $meta[self::FIELDSET_NAME] = [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                        'label'         => __('Features'),
                        'dataScope'     => 'data.product',
                        'collapsible'   => true,
                        'opened'        => false,
                        'sortOrder' => 10,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children'  => [
                'container_' . self::FIELD_NAME => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'formElement'   => 'container',
                                'componentType' => 'container',
                                'breakLine'     => false,
                                'label'         => __('Multiselect from PHP'),
                                'required'      => false,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'children'  => [
                        self::FIELD_NAME => [
                            'arguments' => [
                                'data' => [
                                    'config' => [
                                        'dataType'      => MultiSelect::NAME,
                                        'formElement'   => MultiSelect::NAME,
                                        'visible'       => 1,
                                        'required'      => 0,
                                        'label'         => __('Multiselect from PHP'),
                                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                                        'code'          => self::FIELD_NAME,
                                        'source'        => self::FIELDSET_NAME,
                                        'scopeLabel'    => '[GLOBAL]',
                                        'globalScope'   => true,
                                        'sortOrder'     => 30,
                                        'options'       => [
                                            ['value' => '0', 'label' => __('One')],
                                            ['value' => '1', 'label' => __('Two')],
                                            ['value' => '2', 'label' => __('Three')],
                                            ['value' => '3', 'label' => __('Four')],
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        return $meta;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are correct, the code was a simplified example. Perhaps oversimplified. I've tried to use `modifyData()` as you suggested, thank you. However it does not select the elements. I'll update the code in the OP with running example code to see if we can get to the bottom of this. Thank you.

Comment: I've edited the question with the complete code file and di.xml. Thank you for looking into this Victor ))

Comment: Do you still have any questions or? It's not clear based on your comment or update. I see that you are always set default value and never read value from product. I guess it's some mistake here.

Comment: I've updated code with working example

Comment: Thank you Victor! Your name is appropriate )) I did have the data format returned in `modifyMeta()` wrong, additionally as we both found out `modifyData()` needs to add the field value as a string, not an array. **Thank you!**